# Using variable in th:replace doesn't render template

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use a model attribute from Spring MVC controller in the th:replace section.  In the example, the page variable is a string defult :: default but the top one states the following error.
`TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [default :: default], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "index" - line 53, col 14)`

```
<div th:replace="${page}" th:assert="${!#strings.isEmpty(page)}"></div>

<div th:replace="default :: default"></div>
```

the bottom one works fine.

I have tried a few different processors even including th:replace="@{{page}(page = ${page})}" and what not to try a couple different ways but nothing seems to allow it to be resolved from a variable and like the resolver treats the tag differently.

Here is the controller code.

```
    fun blog(model: Model): String {
        model["page"] = "default :: default"
        return "index"
    }
```

I'm expecting both th:reaplce attributes to act the same.

Answer (score 0):

it's a simple thing. just need the __ to render properly, just need to RTFM.

```
<div th:include="__${page}__" th:if="${!#strings.isEmpty(page)}"></div>
```

I like this better than layouts for a few reasons.